# Curl time's out when calling a long running web service

Tags: curl, amazon-elb

I have a web service which takes more than a minute to finish. I need to call this using curl from a batch job. I've tried passing in options -m 300 --connect-timeout 300 and --keepalive-time 300, but it still fails with error 52. The web service continues to do work and finishes what its supposed to do but the response never comes back because curl times out.
Are there any other options that curl takes in that would help with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the AWS Elastic load balancer has default client connection timeout of 60 seconds. This was causing any client like curl, wget or browser to timeout and in some cases re-trigger the web service. Changing this value to a higher number fixed my issue.
Check out this link for configuring the timeouts in ELB
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/config-idle-timeout.html